# SmartGWT ListGrid validation on newly added row

Tags: validation, smartgwt

I have a ListGrid that is initially empty with no records with three ListGridFields defined.  The first ListGridField is a Name and is editable, the second is a 'Low' value and is NOT editable whose value is set to 0 if it's the first row added, or set to the previous record's high value if it's not the first and the third ListGridField is the 'High' value which is also editable.

The 'High' ListGridField is required and has two validators on it, one being the IntegerRangeValidator with a min of 0 and a max of Integer.MAX_INT.  The second validator is a custom validator I created that ensures the value entered by the user is not equal to or less than the 'Low' value of the record.

```
final MXListGrid rangeGrid = new MXListGrid();

    rangeGrid.setOverflow(Overflow.AUTO);

    rangeGrid.setWidth100();

    rangeGrid.setHeight100();

    rangeGrid.setAutoFetchData(false);

    rangeGrid.setSelectionType(SelectionStyle.SINGLE);

    ListGridField l_description = new ListGridField("description", "Description");

    l_description.setType(ListGridFieldType.TEXT);

    ListGridField l_low = new ListGridField("low", "Low");

    l_low.setType(ListGridFieldType.INTEGER);

    l_low.setCanEdit(false);

    l_low.setCellFormatter(new CellFormatter()
    {
        public String format(Object value, ListGridRecord record, int rowNum, int colNum)
        {
            if (value == null) return null;

            NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getFormat("###,###,###,###");

            try
            {
                return nf.format(((Number) value).longValue());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return value.toString();
            }
        }
    });
    ListGridField l_high = new ListGridField("high", "High");

    l_high.setType(ListGridFieldType.INTEGER);

    l_high.setCellFormatter(new CellFormatter()
    {
        public String format(Object value, ListGridRecord record, int rowNum, int colNum)
        {
            if (value == null) return null;

            NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getFormat("###,###,###,###");

            try
            {
                return nf.format(((Number) value).longValue());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return value.toString();
            }
        }
    });
    IntegerRangeValidator intRangeValidator = new IntegerRangeValidator();

    intRangeValidator.setMax(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    intRangeValidator.setMin(0);

    l_high.setValidators(new MXRangeClassificationValidator(), intRangeValidator);

    l_high.setRequired(true);

    rangeGrid.setFields(l_description, l_low, l_high);

    rangeGrid.setCanEdit(true);

    rangeGrid.setEditEvent(ListGridEditEvent.CLICK);
```

I then have a button on the screen that allows a user to add a new record.  As per the logic above, if it's the first record being added, the low value is set to 0 and the high is set to an empty string or if there are pre-existing records, the new row is added below the currently selected row or at the bottom if no row is selected and the low is set to the previous record's high and the high is set to empty string and always, the focus and cursor get moved from wherever they are to the 'Name' field of the newly added row.

```
final MXButton addRowBtn = new MXButton("Add Row");

    addRowBtn.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler()
    {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event)
        {
            if (rangeGrid.getRecords().length == 0)
            {
                m_rowCount = 0;

                ListGridRecord record = new ListGridRecord();

                record.setAttribute("description", "");

                record.setAttribute("low", 0);

                record.setAttribute("high", "");

                rangeGrid.addData(record);

                rangeGrid.startEditing(m_rowCount, 0, false);

                m_rowCount++;
            }
            else
            {
                RecordList list = rangeGrid.getDataAsRecordList();

                int selectedRow = m_rowCount - 1;

                if (rangeGrid.getSelectedRecord() != null)
                {
                    selectedRow = rangeGrid.getDataAsRecordList().indexOf(rangeGrid.getSelectedRecord());
                }

                ListGridRecord prevRecord = rangeGrid.getRecord(selectedRow);

                ListGridRecord record = new ListGridRecord();

                record.setAttribute("description", "");

                record.setAttribute("low", Long.valueOf(prevRecord.getAttribute("high")));

                record.setAttribute("high", "");

                list.addAt(record, selectedRow + 1);

                rangeGrid.startEditing(selectedRow + 1, 0, false);

                m_rowCount++;
            }
        }
    });
```

I also have added a RowEditorExitHandler to my ListGrid so I can control some UI behaviors upon the return of manually triggering the record validation for the record just exited.

```
// add some row editing validation
    rangeGrid.addRowEditorExitHandler(new RowEditorExitHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onRowEditorExit(RowEditorExitEvent event)
        {
            GWT.log("leaving row: " + event.getRowNum());

            if (!rangeGrid.validateRow(event.getRowNum()))
            {
                saveBtn.disable();

                addRowBtn.disable();
            }
            else
            {
                saveBtn.enable();

                addRowBtn.enable();
            }
        }
    });
```

This all works beautifully if I add a record and immediately enter a faulty value in the 'High' field.  The problem exists if I click the button and add a new row and then click somewhere else on the screen, outside of that row, removing focus from the newly added row.  My RowEditorExitHandler method is triggered, but my manual listGrid.validateRow(event.getRownNum()) is NEVER executed in this scenario.  It does not like the fact that the cell has not been manually edited...it ignores the fact that the user has not provided a valid 'High' value.  I've tried a few things, like adding logic in my RowEditorExitHandler onRowEditorExit method that checks the value of the current row's High value and if it's an empty string or null , update it's value to a bunch of empty spaces and THEN trigger the validateRow method...still does not execute validation.  It's only when I click back into the newly added record's High field and press the space bar a few times or enter an invalid value, does the validation take place.

I need to know how to have my newly added row immediately have its values validated if the user adds the row and then focuses out of the newly added row so I can disable the add row and save buttons immediately.  I don't want to have to do validation upon clicking the save or add row buttons which kind of defeats the purpose of this validation model, but if that's the only solution, then I will have to do it...but it's strange that no matter what I try, only actually typing in the field and then exiting the row triggers the validation...even programmatically changing the values of this field upon exit and programmatically triggering validation has no effect.

Any thoughts?  Sorry for the long-windedness...

Comment: U can try overriding the validateRow method of ListGrid and put some alert/breakpoint to see if is  getting called

Answer (score 0):

I have similar functionality in my project that works for me. I'm converting text copied by user into records and inserting them as new ones into grid. There are couple of minor differences in my code.
This is what I'm doing:

1. adding custom validators on DataSourceField level
2. creating new row by invoking listGrid.startEditingNew(newRecodeObject) in import method
3. invoke listGrid.validateRow(rowNum) in import method

GWT version: 2.5.1, SmartGWT version: 4.0

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you dont need to diference when the list is empty or not to insert a new row, if you just call *listGrid.addData(record);* it will always add it to the end of the list.

```
RecordList list = rangeGrid.getDataAsRecordList();
            int selectedRow = m_rowCount - 1;
            if (rangeGrid.getSelectedRecord() != null)
            {
                selectedRow = rangeGrid.getDataAsRecordList().indexOf(rangeGrid.getSelectedRecord());
            }
            ListGridRecord prevRecord = rangeGrid.getRecord(selectedRow);
            ListGridRecord record = new ListGridRecord();
            record.setAttribute("description", "");
            record.setAttribute("low", Long.valueOf(prevRecord.getAttribute("high")));
            record.setAttribute("high", "");
            list.addAt(record, selectedRow + 1);
            rangeGrid.startEditing(selectedRow + 1, 0, false);
            m_rowCount++;
```

This dont work if a row isn't selected when you click the button.

Then for the validation problem, just add a *rangeGrid.validateRow(m_rowCount);* after the addData, that solves your problem.